# Copy the first file from every folder to a new location in windows

Tags: windows, directory, automation, copy, subdirectory

I have a folder with about 100-200 subfolders. All these have 20-30 Jpegs each. I wish to copy only the first Jpeg file from all the subfolders to a New Folder. Is there a way to automate this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a script like vbScript:

```html
Const rootFolder = "c:\Rootfolder"
Const targetFolder = "c:\TargetFolder"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For Each objFolder In fso.GetFolder(rootFolder).SubFolders
 i = 0
 For Each sFile In objFolder.Files
  If i = 0 then
   fso.GetFile(sFile).Copy targetFolder & "\" & fso.GetFileName(sFile),True
   i = 1
  End if
 Next
Next
```

Comment: Hey Sagi,
Thanks for the reply and thanks again for your help! Could ou also help me in understanding how to use it properly? I'm still new to scripting.

Comment: I tried pasting it on notepad, saving as .wsj and running the script. As test I made new folders in "C" to match with your script, but it shows some error.

Line:10
Char:4
Error: Unterminated entity reference - matching ';' not found

Could you also help me get past this?

Comment: I updated the code. Save it to a text file with as a vbScript file with the .vbs ending.

Comment: Hey Sagi!
Thanks for the update. The code works and is doing wonders for my workflow. Thanks again!